# Symlinking ~/Documents to ~/Google Drive

Tags: finder, symlink, google-apps

I could not understand whether other questions had been answered, or if the answers were valid for my version of OS X (Mavericks), so I'm asking for the definite truth about the following:

**Can I create a symlink so that ~/Documents, which opens with Cmd+Shift+O in the Finder, directly opens my ~/Google Drive folder?**

The Finder won't let me remove the ~/Documents folder, and I wonder whether there is a workaround to that (hard symlink perhaps?). Thanks in advance, and sorry for the n-th question on that topic.

Comment: I symlink a lot of my directories TO my GoogleDrive/DropBox, why not symlink GoogleDrive in your ~/Documents, then have only one folder in there?

Comment: Because I want to be able to use Cmd+Shift+O to access the Google Drive folder directly.

Comment: You are trying to change the behavior of a system default then, which appears to be a duplicate of: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/808/find-and-change-system-shortcut

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure whether I can use the linked answer to assign the Cmd-Shift-O to open the Google Drive folder instead of the Documents folder.

Comment: See this other question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230906/symlink-google-drive/