# Opening iBooks PDFs with Other Apps on iPhone

Tags: ios, pdf, ibook

I have several PDF files in iBooks. I want to open them with the "PDF reader" App instead.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Another method, simpler, not involving clouds is as follows:

1. Touch and hold on book's icon in iBooks, and, from pop-up menu
   choose "Print", see figure below:

[image]

2. On the preview page, do inverse pinch (two fingers spread):
   [image]
3. Now, from Printer options, lower left corner, touch the square to
   send to other applications:
   [image]
4. And choose where to send a copy - in this example I used Documents
   application
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution for MacOS (the question originally didn't specify OS)

To do this, just open the folder which contains your iBooks, right click on a particular book, go to "open with", and choose the program you want (say pdf reader).

This [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259836/where-are-my-ibooks-stored-in-macos-sierra) describes where the iBooks folder is located in Sierra.

It should look something like this: 
[image]

---

Edit:

The OP has now specified that the problem is specific to  iOS. Doing this directly is **impossible** due to the way that the iOS manages storage. iOS doesn't have a file system in the way that macOS does. Each file is associated with the operating  system or a particular app. According to this [website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for iOS developers

> For security purposes, an iOS app’s interactions with the file system are limited to the directories inside the app’s sandbox directory

This means app A can't just go into app B's storage and read a file (say a PDF document).

Thus, you need a workaround. Personally, I use google drive to sync my books (wirelessly) between my mac and my iPhone/tablets. While you could probably do something like this with iCloud I haven't tried that yet so I'll give my solution. All you have to do is

1. Sign up for a google account if you don't have one already
2. [Download](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) the Google Drive macOS app
3. Make a folder  *F* of all your books (iBooks already did this (see my unedited answer)). Then you have 2 choices:
4. Choice 1 (ADVANCED): "Hard link" folder *F* to your Google Drive folder. This will update your google drive automatically every time *F* is edited, say every time you add a new book to *F*. The way to do this is discussed [in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230906/symlink-google-drive). You will need knowledge of the command line.
5. Choice 2 (SIMPLE): Manually copy *F* into your google drive folder. (Note that you can also drag *F* into the google drive folder. **HOWEVER if you do this once *F* is uploaded, *F* will be stored in the (google drive) cloud, and no longer on your computer**.)
6. Download the google drive app on your phone (or tablet or android) and sign in.
7. You can now see the folder *F* on your iphone and any other ios (or Android!!!!!) devices on which you have installed the app.
8. If you have a wifi connection, you can just click on a PDF to open it. If you want to make it so that in the future you can open PDFs without a wifi connection, just follow these [instructions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en).

Here's a screenshot of how it should look.  [image: googledrive]